# Not able to display json value

Tags: python, ansible

I have an inventory which I collected from ansible and I'm reading it with python but I have no sucess to print the values here, so I have the following:

the content below is in a file called "localhost".

```
{
  "ansible_facts": {
    "facter_architecture": "x86_64",
    "facter_bios_release_date": "12/01/2006",
    "facter_bios_vendor": "innotek GmbH",
    "facter_bios_version": "VirtualBox",
    "facter_blockdevice_sda_model": "VBOX HARDDISK",
    "facter_blockdevice_sda_size": 10737418240,
    "facter_blockdevice_sda_vendor": "ATA",
    "facter_blockdevice_sr0_model": "CD-ROM",
    "facter_blockdevice_sr0_size": 1073741312,
    "facter_blockdevice_sr0_vendor": "VBOX",
    "facter_blockdevices": "sda,sr0",
    "facter_boardmanufacturer": "Oracle Corporation",
    "facter_boardproductname": "VirtualBox",
    "facter_boardserialnumber": "0",
    "facter_dhcp_servers": {
      "enp0s3": "10.0.2.2",
      "enp0s8": "192.168.1.1",
      "system": "10.0.2.2"
    },
    "facter_domain": "home",
    "facter_facterversion": "2.4.1",
    "facter_filesystems": "xfs",
    "facter_fqdn": "mylab.home",
    "facter_gid": "root",
    "facter_hardwareisa": "x86_64",
    "facter_hardwaremodel": "x86_64",
    "facter_hostname": "mylab",
    "facter_id": "root",
    "facter_interfaces": "enp0s3,enp0s8,lo",
    "facter_ipaddress": "10.0.2.15",
    "facter_ipaddress_enp0s3": "10.0.2.15",
    "facter_ipaddress_enp0s8": "192.168.1.101",
    "facter_ipaddress_lo": "127.0.0.1",
    "facter_is_virtual": true,
    "facter_kernel": "Linux",
    "facter_kernelmajversion": "3.10",
    "facter_kernelrelease": "3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64",
    "facter_kernelversion": "3.10.0",
    "facter_macaddress": "08:00:27:dd:47:a8",
    "facter_macaddress_enp0s3": "08:00:27:dd:47:a8",
    "facter_macaddress_enp0s8": "08:00:27:12:ce:46",
    "facter_manufacturer": "innotek GmbH",
    "facter_memoryfree": "730.39 MB",
    "facter_memoryfree_mb": "730.39",
    "facter_memorysize": "990.98 MB",
    "facter_memorysize_mb": "990.98",
    "facter_mtu_enp0s3": 1500,
    "facter_mtu_enp0s8": 1500,
    "facter_mtu_lo": 65536,
    "facter_netmask": "255.255.255.0",
    "facter_netmask_enp0s3": "255.255.255.0",
    "facter_netmask_enp0s8": "255.255.255.0",
    "facter_netmask_lo": "255.0.0.0",
    "facter_network_enp0s3": "10.0.2.0",
    "facter_network_enp0s8": "192.168.1.0",
    "facter_network_lo": "127.0.0.0",
    "facter_operatingsystem": "CentOS",
    "facter_operatingsystemmajrelease": "7",
    "facter_operatingsystemrelease": "7.8.2003",
    "facter_os": {
      "family": "RedHat",
      "name": "CentOS",
      "release": {
        "full": "7.8.2003",
        "major": "7",
        "minor": "8"
      }
    },
    "facter_osfamily": "RedHat",
    "facter_partitions": {
      "sda1": {
        "filesystem": "xfs",
        "mount": "/boot",
        "size": "2097152",
        "uuid": "987fb5e2-f636-423b-997d-c2654993708c"
      },
      "sda2": {
        "filesystem": "LVM2_member",
        "size": "18872320"
      }
    },
    "facter_path": "/root/.rbenv/shims:/root/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/python3:/root/bin",
    "facter_physicalprocessorcount": 1,
    "facter_processor0": "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5350U CPU @ 1.80GHz",
    "facter_processorcount": 1,
    "facter_processors": {
      "count": 1,
      "models": [
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5350U CPU @ 1.80GHz"
      ],
      "physicalcount": 1
    },
    "facter_productname": "VirtualBox",
    "facter_ps": "ps -ef",
    "facter_rubyplatform": "x86_64-linux",
    "facter_rubysitedir": "/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/",
    "facter_rubyversion": "2.0.0",
    "facter_selinux": false,
    "facter_serialnumber": "0",
    "facter_sshecdsakey": "AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBE8u+HCceoSA9mrw1oboY4sAXhkgp4CBTe8QjuW2OAeYIQS7LblPztfQmJFkXpHTWhLvSBYglzcuZiJOzUbZQ/0=",
    "facter_sshed25519key": "AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIDutjvzHFEKqc0bprmbkm9ZUoADflkan6dnCVcYsGOTT",
    "facter_sshfp_ecdsa": "SSHFP 3 1 2190a1073f110b50ed6fb912cd04144603a85098\nSSHFP 3 2 3a708ee555593b0ad5a2f1992ae949d56d2f3556c37b201ef683d4a3ea850660",
    "facter_sshfp_ed25519": "SSHFP 4 1 695978669c105b4a3a06c4b9a685020363b72c67\nSSHFP 4 2 794f24ad5bd7b91a1d3a0f484ceb166088ac8d57e3e1682e8b8fe006fde1c169",
    "facter_sshfp_rsa": "SSHFP 1 1 07afd9583d0785ac923230bef3b0d0ffeefad097\nSSHFP 1 2 29158514b311cc7687fa1c3aab1fa1abee0f2f581eb3d607a6b4ffb8ff258d59",
    "facter_sshrsakey": "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCtgyTEG+VnEnXiiaP4tFpIiWwWfqxdW8BCATa5W9QE0AsfY1OiFoLRXYGqhL72q0N+VTHQGB7eB1sd9Nas48erDzZXpgLoIDqM1pa/vT/j/SygQB2rwgo2wga0tw+zW1cw+sELjXHAYsi8DADKbGlX2cCeT3MKeWdkg+BQogf74Sy4NEPbYhILXPfvt3cJxCM02sIn/eQL+n06iSzesUIEy5n+AlRgACR3zHnk5rtHipj/RzmPv+J0V3du7+g6/3TiKDcBTNHtb8QSa4DSGkmbW7Wdhvnw9GyhO5ySGB2G3rmLiVIm9vdjB9L/X/L2g8TB5+/dO52UxUSX17nwzuJB",
    "facter_swapfree": "1024.00 MB",
    "facter_swapfree_mb": "1024.00",
    "facter_swapsize": "1024.00 MB",
    "facter_swapsize_mb": "1024.00",
    "facter_system_uptime": {
      "days": 0,
      "hours": 3,
      "seconds": 12984,
      "uptime": "3:36 hours"
    },
    "facter_timezone": "CEST",
    "facter_type": "Other",
    "facter_uniqueid": "000a0f02",
    "facter_uptime": "3:36 hours",
    "facter_uptime_days": 0,
    "facter_uptime_hours": 3,
    "facter_uptime_seconds": 12984,
    "facter_uuid": "b64ed9b0-7168-4e49-a34a-90e6ea6f751a",
    "facter_virtual": "kvm"
  },
  "changed": false
}
```

I have the following code.
I tried a lot of deferents stuffs, but somehow it complains about `"list indices must be integers or slices, not str"`

```
import json

dict = []
with open('localhost', 'r') as jsonfile:
    myfile = json.load(jsonfile)


result = json.dumps(myfile, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
dict.append(result)

print(dict['ansible_facts'])
```

From this list I need to extract
**facter_system_uptime** and **facter_hostname** only but I had no success.

I tried to put in a loop, but still same issue.

```
for data in dict['ansible_facts']:
    print(data)
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: You have declared your `dict` variable as a list, not a dictionary. Update it to be `dict = {}`. Also, `dict` is a callable that will instantiate a new variable of type dictionary, e.g. `items = dict()`. So I would recommend changing your variable name.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to use `json.dumps` because you've already used `json.load` to deserialize the JSON document to a Python object.

```
import json

with open("localhost") as jsonfile:
    myfile = json.load(jsonfile)

print(myfile["ansible_facts"]["facter_system_uptime"])
print(myfile["ansible_facts"]["facter_hostname"])
```

Comment: if I do the below:

`import json

with open('localhost', 'r') as jsonfile:
    myfile = json.load(jsonfile)
    for key, value in myfile['ansible_facts'].items():
        print(key, value['facter_system_uptime'])
        print(key, value['facter_hostname'])`
Give me the error.

    `print(key, value['facter_system_uptime'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: I know @Vishal Singh 
Your recommendation worked thanks.
But I also need to be readable from loop as well.
Sorry but I'm learning, don't be rude. :(

Comment: @AndersonSoares didn't mean to be rude. I think you are going the wrong way this is not how you use a dictionary. This might help https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, I will study more.

Comment: if you just need to access a single key as you suggested in your question you don't need loops. loops will be used here if these keys would be present in various other places.

Comment: yes but In a short future I will need to access key in a loop as well, I will find out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `dict` as the name for a variable - it shadows the builtin and will cause you problems.
2. You created a list (`mydict = []`) and then you appended your parsed json to it.  That means, to access it, you must use `mydict[0]['ansible_facts']`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what ansible is, but to my knowledge, your error is because you initilized dict as a list:

```
dict = []
```

which you can access its elements by numerical indices, but instead you gave it a string:

```
print(dict['ansible_facts'])
```

this is how you initialize a dictionary:

```
dict = {}
```

Comment: if i change from [] to {} I cannot append.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

1. You have created a list instead of dict
2. You have used reserved key(dict) as variable name

So the final code should be something like

```
import json
    
with open('localhost', 'r') as jsonfile:
    myfile = json.load(jsonfile)
    print(myfile['ansible_facts']['facter_system_uptime'])
    print(myfile['ansible_facts']['facter_hostname'])
```

If you want to print all the data using loop
You can iterate on `myfile['ansible_facts']` like this.

```
import json
    
with open('localhost', 'r') as jsonfile:
    myfile = json.load(jsonfile)
    for key, value in myfile['ansible_facts'].items():
        print(key, value)
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I'm not understanding.
I can print in loop if I use key and value, but why i cannot print the value in loop like the below?
this is the error:

    `print(key['facter_system_uptime'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

@Kaushal






          
          
          
          
          
          
          
`import json

with open('localhost', 'r') as jsonfile:
    myfile = json.load(jsonfile)
    for key, value in myfile['ansible_facts'].items():
        print(key['facter_system_uptime'])
        print(value['facter_hostname'])`

Comment: You have to stop using dict as a variable. It is a reserved word in python.use anything else like : my_dictionary = {}. And the other problem is you are using list, please read about list , dictionary and their iteration. It's very basic python.